# user profiles in phonegap app

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I am planning out development of an iPhone app using html/js and phonegap. I am planning on having user profiles as well as a "friends" feed that pulls in actions that your friends have done.

Is incorporating user profiles possible? Will I have to have a non mobile version website for users to log in to and enter content in their profiles and then use something like JSON to pull in the data from the user profiles and display it in the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed you will have to provide some server side storage to save the user profile, history and/or actions

The iPhone app will fed by the server side interface you will implement

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. So it is possible for users to be able to change and update their profile from the iPhone? Basically, all user actions can take place on the iPhone, they don't even need to access an external site, as long as the info is saved to a server and called to the app through JSON requests?

Comment: Yes basically you could store bulk of user actions, locally but then you will need to upload these actions and changes to the shared server, so that the other devices will be able to read and update the other people profiles.

Please dont forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: Ok great thanks Omar. I will accept when Stackoverflow lets me in two minutes :) So basically, I can just create the profiles using javascript right? The user would input the info which would be saved to the database and then called with JSON?

Comment: i would suggest creating the profile in the webserver, then each device would request it, update it and resend it to the webserver

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can actually store data in a local database and you can also synchronize (send and receive) data using ajax. you need of course a webserver managing the main database. i am not sure, but i think you have to white list the domain of your server.

Comment: How will he be able to send and recieve data to/and from other devices, will you suggest to implement it as a direct connection to all the "friend" devices?

Comment: No, I would run a web server with PHP/MySQL and create an api where the app can use AJAX to synchronize with. Make sure that you use password protection and may be even encryption.

Comment: So what would the PHP need to be for?

Comment: You write the server side script of the AJAX in PHP (or another server side scripting language like Perl, ASP, Ruby and so on). The app uses Javascript to connect to the server side script, which checks the user password and retrieves the requested data (you can filter or limit the output) and sends the information back to the JavaScript as json or xml. [Wikipedia: AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

Comment: Regarding to your other question from before. I would not do an app to app connection. It is too much hassle with the protocols and you have too less control over it. It also is difficult to keep secure. You need one server which holds the passwords and collects and serves the information. Especially when user change passwords, it is easier than updating the connections all through the network. Also, you may expose the user ip addresses to other users with direct connections and open other security issues.